# Get this error message when trying to register a service worker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script

Tags: service, progressive-web-apps, registration, worker

Developing with Django in a LiteSpeed droplet.
Messages in Chrome developer tools console:
A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
narunoko.com/:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://narunoko.com/') with script ('https://narunoko.com/sWorker.js'): A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
My service worker: sWorker.js is in the root directory of my app
The manifest manifest.json is also in the root directory and its content is:

```
{
   "name": "Narunoko",
   "short_name": "Narunoko",
   "start_url": "/",
   "display": "standalone",
   "background_color": "#21262d",
   "theme_color": "#493174",
   "description": "App for Arts and Culture",
   "dir": "ltr",
   "lang": "en-US",
   "orientation": "any",
   "icons": [{
       "src": "/static/myapp/icons/aurss.96x96.png",
       "type": "image/png",
       "sizes": "96x96"
   }, {
       "src": "/static/myapp/icons/aurss.512x512.png",
       "type": "image/png",
       "sizes": "512x512"
   }]
}
```

The script for registering the service worker is in my base.html file and its content is:

```
<script>
    if (!navigator.serviceWorker.controller) 
       navigator.serviceWorker.register("/sWorker.js").then(function(reg) {
           console.log("Service worker has been registered for scope: " + reg.scope);
       });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The django serves the static,  we must set a static for static files and run manage.py collectstatic  to collect all static files into STATIC_URL. Hope this can give you some idea, https://docs.litespeedtech.com/cloud/images/django/#set-up-demo-django-project

Comment: My question is related to the error when adding a service worker to my page

Comment: Yes, it's django setup issue, I got a 404 as well when visiting  https://narunoko.com/sWorker.js

Comment: Eric, can you tell me what to do to solve this setup isse?